# C# Windows forms Blink label

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, timer

In a windows forms dialog I have a `Listview` that contains almost 2000 rows. Each row has a checkbox. To make it easy for the user I have two `Labels` above the Listview to show any active filter AND how many rows are selected (checked).

To emphasize when a filter or selection is changed, I want to make the label blink. Therefore I extended the `Label` class to support blink automatically when the text is changed.
But it is not working!

When I use `Windows.Forms.Timer()` the label **might** blink once or twice, but not always, and often it ends up hidden.

When I use `System.Timers.Timer()` I get a `crossthreadException` even though I use `InvokeRequired`.

WHAT IS WRONG :(

```
class BlinkLabel : Label
{
    private int _blinkFrequency = 621;
    private int _maxNumberOfBlinks = 15;
    private int _blinkCount = 20;
    private bool _isBlinking = false;
    //System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    Timer _timer = new Timer();

    public BlinkLabel(){}
    public BlinkLabel(int frequency, int maxNrBlinks)
    {
        _blinkFrequency = frequency;
        _maxNumberOfBlinks = 15;
    }
    protected override void OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        if (!_isBlinking)
        {
            base.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
            StartBlink();
        }
    }
    public void StartBlink()
    {
        this._isBlinking = true;
        base.Visible = true;
        this._timer.Interval = this._blinkFrequency;
        this._timer.Enabled = true;
        //this._timer.AutoReset = true;
        //this._timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        this._timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
        this._timer.Start();
    }

    void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //SYSTEM.TIMERS.TIMER() TICK
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { this._timer_Elapsed(sender, e); }));
        }
        else
        {
            base.Visible = !base.Visible;
            this._blinkCount++;
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (this._blinkCount >= this._maxNumberOfBlinks)
            {
                this._timer.Stop();
                this._blinkCount = 0;
                base.Visible = true;
                this._isBlinking = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //WINDOWS.FORMS.TIMER TICK
        this.Visible = !this.Visible;
        this._blinkCount++;
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (this._blinkCount >= this._maxNumberOfBlinks)
        {
            this._timer.Stop();
            this._blinkCount = 0;
            //base.Visible = true;
            this.Visible = true;
            this._isBlinking = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bonus question: Im a bit confused whether to use THIS or BASE inside my methods when changing properties of the Label. Which one should I use?

Comment: I think you missed an `else`, `if (this.InvokeRequired) { ... } else { ... }`.

Comment: I'll suggest you to handle paint to achieve this changing `Visible` is not a good idea. and use only `Windows.Forms.Timer`

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria: Correct, it somehow fell off when I copy/pasted the code. The problem remains though

Comment: OnPaint() is probably the way to go with this, check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1355/Professional-C-Graphics-with-GDI) very comprehensive beginners guide

Comment: @iabbott: Wow, that was a lengthy artical. Is that really necessary to make Label blink?

Comment: @David no not all of it, that will guide you through all the things you would need to get started with drawing on a userform. I would think for you that only the first few paragraphs would be enough, just showing how to draw a rectangle and how to make sure it is updated properly. I will add an answer with what I think you would need to do to make this work for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes, makes it hard to debug.  Principal problems are that you forget to reset _blinkCount back to 0.  And very detrimental, you are subscribing the Tick event handler over and over again, causing the Tick event handler to run multiple times for each tick.  Using Application.DoEvents() is especially wrong, also makes it next to impossible to debug.

A rewrite of this code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class BlinkLabel : Label {
    private const int _maxNumberOfBlinks = 2 * 3;
    private int _blinkCount = 0;
    private Timer _timer;
    private Color oldColor;

    public BlinkLabel() {
        this._timer = new Timer();
        this._timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
        this._timer.Interval = 621;
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs e) {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        if (!this._timer.Enabled && base.IsHandleCreated) StartBlink();
    }

    public void StartBlink() {
        this._blinkCount = 0; 
        base.Visible = true;
        this.oldColor = base.ForeColor;
        base.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple; 
        this._timer.Start();
    }

    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        base.Visible = !base.Visible;
        this._blinkCount++;
        if (this._blinkCount >= _maxNumberOfBlinks) {
            this._timer.Stop();
            base.Visible = true;
            base.ForeColor = oldColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I moved the subscription of the eventhandler to the Constructor method it all worked like a charm. Thanks for spotting the problem. Calling DoEvents() was a me-panicking-solution when I was'nt able to solve the problem. Anyways, big thx!

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, here is the basics for painting a rectangle onto your form (from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1355/Professional-C-Graphics-with-GDI) article):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Get your rectangle size from your text box
        Rectangle tbSize = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 20); 

        // invalSize must be slightly bigger due to where the lines are drawn
        Rectangle invalSize = new Rectangle(10, 10, 51, 21); 

        Timer _timer = new Timer();
        bool painting = true;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this._timer.Interval = 1000;
            this._timer.Enabled = true;
            this._timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
            this._timer.Start();
        }


        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            if (painting)
            {
                // e.Graphics uses what Windows has decided needs to be repainted
                // eg only the small rectangle we are drawing, or our rect and
                // a control on the other side of the form
                DrawBorderRect(tbSize, e.Graphics); 
            }
        }

        private void DrawBorderRect(Rectangle coords, Graphics dc)
        {
            Pen bluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 1);
            dc.DrawRectangle(bluePen, coords);
        }

        private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            painting = !painting;

            // This will make Windows raise a paint event so we don't have to.
            // Doing it this way allows Windows to combine multiple small paint
            // events to maximise efficiency
            this.Invalidate(invalSize); 
        }

    }
}
```

Just chuck that into a new form and watch the blinking blue box :)